# Is there any security problem in hosting a crossdomain.xml in our servers?

Tags: flash

It was asked to us to host a crossdomain.xml file in our servers in order to access some XML files we have developed.
The content of this file is:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Is it OK?

Answer (score 2):

Well that lets any flash app from any port load XML data from your domain.

That being said, you do need to set a bunch of other data in order for it to be a valid cross-domain policy file (there were new required elements added with FP9)

Here's the full spec for cross-domain policies:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

You can find all of the most recent security recommendations for cross-domain policy files (and everything else concerning the Flash Player) here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player10_security_wp.html

Answer (score 0):

This will allow flash content hosted from anywhere to load data directly into a client from your services, and can have [significant security implications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/cross_domain_policy.html), depending on your authentication model and setup.